# Extract field from JSON response with Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I have a task which performs a GET request to a page. The response's body is a JSON like the following.

```
 {
  "ips": [
    {
      "organization": "1233124121",
      "reverse": null,
      "id": "1321411312",
      "server": {
        "id": "1321411",
        "name": "name1"
      },
      "address": "x.x.x.x"
    },
    {
      "organization": "2398479823",
      "reverse": null,
      "id": "2418209841",
      "server": {
        "id": "234979823",
        "name": "name2"
      },
      "address": "x.x.x.x"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the fields id and address, and tried (for id field):

```
tasks:
  - name: get request                                           
    uri:
      url: "https://myurl.com/ips"
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200
      headers:
        Content-Type: "application/json"
        X-Auth-Token: "0010101010"
      body_format: json
    register: json_response 


  - name: copy ip_json content into a file
    copy: content={{json_response.json.ips.id}} dest="/dest_path/json_response.txt"
```

but I get this error:

the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable
 that is undefined. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'id'..

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'id'

`json_response.json.ips` is a list.

You either need to choose one element (first?): `json_response.json.ips[0].id`.

Or process this list for example with `map` or `json_query` filters if you need all ids.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible command to copy to file:

```
  copy:
    content: "{{ output.stdout[0] }}"
    dest: "~/ansible/local/facts/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```